# When I try running this class in eclipse, another class gets executed

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this class called deepToe_2. Whenever I click on the shortcut key for run, eclipse runs another class called TicTacToe which I had previously ran.
I have tried making changes to run cofig but it still does not seem to work.
Here is my code :

```
package deepToe;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import deepToe.deepToe_2.buttonListener;

public class deepToe_2 extends JPanel {

JButton buttons[] = new JButton[9]; 
int alternate = 0;
String MotherBoard[] = {"","","","","","","","",""};
String board[];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame window = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.getContentPane().add(new TicTacToe());
    window.setBounds(300,200,300,300);
    window.setVisible(true);
}

public deepToe_2()
{
  setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
  initializebuttons();
  toss();
}

public void toss(){
    Random ran = new Random();
    int r = ran.nextInt(2);
    if(r == 1){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "deepToe goes First.");
        alternate++;
        deepToe();
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "deepToe goes First.");
        alternate++;
        deepToe();
    }
}

public void deepToe() {
    if(alternate == 1) {
        buttons[4].setText("O");
    }else {
        int moves[] = {-1000,-1000,-1000,-1000,-1000,-1000,-1000,-1000,-1000};
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            board = MotherBoard;
            if(board[i] == "") {
                board[i] = "O";
                moves[i] = evaluateBoard();
            }
        }
        int high = -999, final_move = -1;
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if(moves[j] > high){
                high = moves[j];
                final_move = j;
            }
        }
        buttons[final_move].setText("O");
    }
    updateMotherBoard();
    if(!(checkResults())) alternate++;
}

public int evaluateBoard() {
    int x = 0;
    if(canSomeoneWin("O") != -1) x += 2;
    if(canSomeoneWin("X") != -1) x -= 2;
    return x;
}

public void updateMotherBoard() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        MotherBoard[i] = buttons[i].getText();
    }
}

public int canSomeoneWin(String c) {
    int x = 0, y = 1, z = 2;
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        if((board[y] == board[z])&&(board[y] == c)&&(board[x] == "")) return x;
        if((board[x] == board[z])&&(board[x] == c)&&(board[y] == "")) return y;
        if((board[x] == board[y])&&(board[x] == c)&&(board[z] == "")) return z;
        x += 3;
        y += 3;
        z += 3;
    }
    x = 0; y = 3; z = 6;
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        if((board[y] == board[z])&&(board[y] == c)&&(board[x] == "")) return x;
        if((board[x] == board[z])&&(board[x] == c)&&(board[y] == "")) return y;
        if((board[x] == board[y])&&(board[x] == c)&&(board[z] == "")) return z;
        x++;
        y++;
        z++;
    }
    x = 0; y = 4; z = 8;
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
        if((board[y] == board[z])&&(board[y] == c)&&(board[x] == "")) return x;
        if((board[x] == board[z])&&(board[x] == c)&&(board[y] == "")) return y;
        if((board[x] == board[y])&&(board[x] == c)&&(board[z] == "")) return z;
        x = 2; z = 6;
    }
    return -1;

}

public void initializebuttons()
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        buttons[i] = new JButton();
        buttons[i].setText("");
        buttons[i].addActionListener(new buttonListener());

        add(buttons[i]);           
    }
    buttons[5].setText("X");

}

public class buttonListener implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {

        JButton buttonClicked = (JButton)e.getSource(); 

        if((alternate%2 == 0)&&(buttonClicked.getText().equals(""))){
            buttonClicked.setText("X");
            updateMotherBoard();
            if(!(checkResults())) {
                alternate++;
                deepToe();
            }
        }

    }
}

    public boolean checkResults(){
        if(checkForWin())
        {
            if(alternate%2 == 0)
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Human wins. Great Job!!!");
            else
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "deepToe wins.");  
            return true;
        }else{
            if(checkForDraw()){
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Draw. Good game.");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

    public boolean checkForDraw() {
        boolean yes = true;
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
            if(buttons[j].getText().equals("")) yes = false;
        }
        return yes;
    }

    public boolean checkForWin()
    {
        if( checkAdjacent(0,1) && checkAdjacent(1,2) ) //no need to put " == true" because the default check is for true
            return true;
        else if( checkAdjacent(3,4) && checkAdjacent(4,5) )
            return true;
        else if ( checkAdjacent(6,7) && checkAdjacent(7,8))
            return true;
        else if ( checkAdjacent(0,3) && checkAdjacent(3,6))
            return true;  
        else if ( checkAdjacent(1,4) && checkAdjacent(4,7))
            return true;
        else if ( checkAdjacent(2,5) && checkAdjacent(5,8))
            return true;
        else if ( checkAdjacent(0,4) && checkAdjacent(4,8))
            return true;  
        else if ( checkAdjacent(2,4) && checkAdjacent(4,6))
            return true;
        else 
            return false;


    }

    public boolean checkAdjacent(int a, int b)
    {
        if ( buttons[a].getText().equals(buttons[b].getText()) && !buttons[a].getText().equals("") )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: use "Run AS ... "

Comment: How you know that it is running the other class and not this?

Answer (score 1):

It probably **IS** running this class, but you are inserting the wrong panel in your frame:

```
window.getContentPane().add(new TicTacToe());
```

it should be `deepToe_2` like in

```
window.getContentPane().add(new deepToe_2());
```

since there is no other reference to that class in the poseted code.

Just to be sure change the frame's title:

```
JFrame window = new JFrame("Deep Toe 2");  // or so
```

I also would encourage you to (learn to) use the debugger, would b helpful to identify such problems...

Answer (score 0):

Right click either in your class file or the class itself and click Run As -> Java Application

Comment: Tried it. It didn't work. It ran the previous program itself. Please help me. Thanks for trying, you are great.

Comment: Try to clean your project

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I don't know if this will help you in anyway to find the solution but there is a yellow line below the class name.

Comment: I renamed my class to deepToe2 and put it in a different package called deepToe_2. Then when I ran it I got an error saying : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at deepToe_2.deepToe2.main(deepToe2.java:21)

Answer (score 0):

you need just to double click your class and then run the program from where ever you want. you can right click as suggested by kkflf or run it from shortcut key as you used to do.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Tried it. It didn't work. It ran the previous program itself. Please help me. Thanks for trying, you are great.

Comment: I don't know if this will help you in anyway to find the solution but there is a yellow line below the class name.

Comment: @DeepCraft the yellow line is indicating there is a warning... hover over it to read it or open/look for the "Problems" view (Menu: Window -> Show View... -> Problems) - this is probably because the "serial version ID" is missing and can be ignored (for now)

Comment: Are you sure it is another example that is running? because from what I see, it is your frame that is titled as Tic Tac Toe in your main method: